# How to set custom ringtone to contact in android

Tags: android

Here is my code to update contact and set the custom ring tune it is running successfully but it is not working and I'm using API 9

```
        sound = new File(folder,SONG);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, sound.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "1-800-hotlinebling");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Umair Ali");
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);
                values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactID);
                values.putNull(ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE);
                Uri localUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactID);
                getContentResolver().update(localUri, values, null, null);
```

Comment: It may not working because of API 9, which is lack of many features. If you can't afford devices with higher API use emulator like Genymotion or try to find a custom ROM for your device ;-)

Comment: I also test on API 19

Answer (score 0):

In StackOverflow similar issue [Setting contact custom ringtone, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230444/setting-contact-custom-ringtone-how) you would find that answer

> I found out how it works. Below you can see the fixed code code:
>
> ```
>     Uri contactData = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;      String contactId = contactData.getLastPathSegment();
>           Cursor localCursor = managedQuery(contactData, PROJECTION, null, null, null);       localCursor.move(120/*CONTACT ID NUMBER*/);
>
>   String str1 =
>   localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
>   String str2 =
>   localCursor.getString(localCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("display_name"));
>   Uri localUri =
>   Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, str1);
>   ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
>
>   localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
>   localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE,
>   f.getAbsolutePath()+"/Adventure.ogg");
>   getContentResolver().update(localUri, localContentValues, null, null);      
>   Toast.makeText(this, "Ringtone assigned to: " + str2, 0).show();
> ```
>
> Just change the contact id number to the id of the contact you want to
>   change.

Hope it help

Comment: lol. I also do this. same code. I'm new in android. I need to install google play services for that or not?

Comment: in this issue is another answer. No, I don't feel that you need Googles services. Maybe you need to add some permissions in AndroidManifest

Comment: @AbdullahSheikh What permissions did u add?